# Modify smartcite from biblatex to change behaviour based on prenote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, brackets

I have a question about the smartcite command from biblatex.

I redefined it in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
               \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite} \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}
   [\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{ABC,
  author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schöyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
  title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
  year = {1979},
  publisher = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
   Normal text\footnote{Some text \autocite[][20]{ABC}}.}
\end{document}
```

With this I get a footnote citation within the normal text and a parenthesized citation in a footnote when using the `\autocite` command.

The problem is when I use e.g. `\footnote{Some text \autocite[][20]{ABC}}.}` I get as result `Some text ([ABC, S. 20]).` but what I would like to see is `Some text [ABC, S. 20].` when I don't give a prenote.
But when there is a prenote like `\footnote{Some text \autocite[see][20]{ABC}}.}` I would like to get `Some text (see [ABC, S. 20]).` as a result.

I tried to redefine the `\smartcite` command with:

```
   \DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote{\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{prenote}}{\textnormal}{\mkbibparens}}{\mkbibfootnote}]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
               \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite} \usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
```

but it seems like the `\ifthenelse` command has no effect.

Has anybody an idea how to fix it?

Regards

Comment: It seems as though the `\iffieldundef{prenote}` is not available in the wrapper argument of `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\iffieldundef{prenote}` does not seem to be available to `biblatex` in the wrapper argument to `\DeclareCiteCommand`, so we have to delay the test until it is possible.

This can be done as follows

```
\newtoggle{weareinfootnote}
\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{false}

\newbibmacro*{smartprenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\iftoggle{weareinfootnote}
       {\bibopenparen}%
       {}%
     \printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote{\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{true}}{\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{false}\mkbibfootnote}]
    {\usebibmacro{smartprenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and test {\iftoggle{weareinfootnote}}}
      {\bibcloseparen}%
      {}}
```

`smartprenote` prints an opening parenthesis additionally to the prenote if it is in a `\footnote`. Finally in the "postcode" section, we close the parentheses if a prenote is present in a footnote.
We cannot use the standard `\iffootnote` test in the citation command since it will always yield true (if it was called in a footnote it obviously does, while if it was called in-text, we start a footnote ourselves resulting in `\iffootnote` evaluating to true), so we define a toggle `weareinfootnote` that checks whether we were in a footnote before the command was issued.

Note that this might go horribly wrong with multiple citations or `\smartcites` code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{weareinfootnote}
\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{false}

\newbibmacro*{smartprenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\iftoggle{weareinfootnote}
       {\bibopenparen}%
       {}%
     \printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote{\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{true}}{\settoggle{weareinfootnote}{false}\mkbibfootnote}]
    {\usebibmacro{smartprenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}\usebibmacro{postnote}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and test {\iftoggle{weareinfootnote}}}
      {\bibcloseparen}%
      {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
   Normal in-text cite \autocite[20]{wilde} indeed\autocite[see][20]{wilde}. Normal text\footnote{Some text \autocite[][20]{wilde}} and\footnote{Some text \autocite[see][20]{wilde}}.

   Normal in-text cite \autocite{wilde,cicero} indeed \autocite[see][]{wilde,cicero}. Normal text\footnote{Some text \autocite{wilde,cicero}} and\footnote{Some text \autocite[see][]{wilde,cicero}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you works great. One thing, I don't realize till I implement your solution. When I write `Normal in-text cite \autocite[see][20]{wilde}.` I have the problem that I get `(see [Wil99, p. 20])` in the footnote which looks a bit odd it should be `See [Wil99, p. 20]`. Is this possible? I think in this case a test if one came from the normal text and went into the footnote or a test if the prenote is the first text in the footnote is required.

Comment: @user2653422 Thanks for catching that, it was thanks to `biblatex`'s `\iffootnote`, I have changed that. Do you have any thoughts about citations with multiple keys (and post and pre notes) or the multicite version?

Comment: Nice, works flawless. For the multi citations I use the `\autocites(see)()[][]{key1}[][]{key2}`, which results in the desired output, even when I use pre notes for a concrete key. Only for `\footnote{Some text \autocites()()[][]{key1}[][]{key2}}` one can argue that the round brackets are unnecessary, but I wouldn't type it that way.

Comment: @user2653422 OK, glad to hear it works.